# How to Sort Firebase data by date stored as Value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort data which is stored in Firebase database using date. The current storing structure is:

```
 date: "3/1/2018"
 description: "Some Description"
 time: "6 : 24"
 title: "Some Title"
```

So by using Recyclerview I am only able to get data in alphabetically sorted manner. How to use the function orderByValue to sort this data using the date?

Like if there are three events first on 02/05/18 second on 01/05/18 and third on 05/05/18 I want the data to be displayed as the most recent will be on 01/05/18 then on 02/05/18 and then 05/05/18.

I've read various questions on Stack Overflow regarding this but none of them helped me to get my problem solved.

Comment: Your date format is a String, it would be best if your stored it as a Unix Timestamp which is of type `long` or `int`. This makes it incredibly easy to order by.

Comment: I use a dialog to get date from user side, How can I convert it to Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store the data in miliseconds, is not that hard, and then you can bring the data and parse it in Date , look at this snippet

```
   try{

         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
                            Date startDate = df.parse(dateStr);
                            dateStr = String.valueOf(startDate.getTime() / 1000);

   } else {
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here you can get a server time in miliseconds in google

or if you want to get the time from the phone

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

and you can convert those miliseconds into date

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String myDate = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(HERE_YOUR_MILIS_DATE) * 1000L));
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks I converted the date into milliseconds and stored it in firebase. Then at the time of retrieving the data I used orderByChild("date"); and everything worked as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the date differently as you will have a very difficult time doing it this way (you'd have to do it in the client). Instead you should store your date as a timestamp like so:

```
{
    date: 1514978640000,
    description: "Some Description"
    title: "Some Title"
}
```

At the same time you can have one field store both date and time and then convert it wherever you are using it. Sorting becomes trivial then.

Comment: So now I have to change entire code? Is there any way I can convert the String date to timestamp?

Comment: not entire code, just 2 lines where you upload the date

Comment: Got that Thank you :)

Comment: If you already have a lot of data in your database you will have to convert it, but that's a one-time thing.